# Relation between computation of curl and divergence and their formal definitions

Tags: definition, differentiation, mathematics, vector-fields, calculus

both divergence and curl of a vector field have a formal definition, however, we don't use these definitions when we compute the divergence or curl.
so can we just derive the computations from the definitions?

Comment: What do you mean with 'we don't use these definitions'?, because I think we do. Or can you give the definitions?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I just want to know how to derive the formula for the curl or divergence from their formal definitions

Comment: For some intuition on the $del$ operator formulas of divergence and curl, take a look at the last portion of this video (the whole thing is excellent): 10:18-13:28 https://youtu.be/rB83DpBJQsE